# Steam on ubuntu 13.04 won`t launch Garry`s Mod. Error: Could not load library content (Unknown error)

Tags: games, steam

I have steam installed on Ubuntu 13.04 with Garrys Mod, downloaded. When i try to launch the game, it returns with an error " Could not load library content (Unknown error)".
Team Fortress 2 seems to work just fine. The graphics are Intel Core i5 intergrated graphics (Sandy Bridge). 
Tried to reinstall the game, that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a 64bit system, but you need 32bit libs:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`